# Polyline split at node in QGIS

Tags: qgis, mapinfo, line, splitting

How can I divide a polyline at a specific node with QGIS (version 2.12.3-Lyon)?

I was looking for something similar to MapInfo tool "Polyline split at node" which is this simple:

1. Make your layer editable
2. Select the polyline to be splitted
3. Click on "Reshape" (which shows all nodes)
4. Select the node where you want to split the polyline
5. From the menu "Objets" select "Polyline Split at Node"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

QGIS can do the same.  On the Advance Digitizing Toolbar is the 'Split Features' button: [image]

It appears more simple than MapInfo.

1) Make the layer editable

2) Select the 'Split Features' tool

3) Select the node you wish to split at.

This work with polygons also.

Comment: I have tried to split my polyline following this procedure and I can't get it right. Can I reformulate my question with a picture showing exactly what I need?

Comment: If it is going to change the  core question then I'd say no as an answer has already been accepted.  Probably best to ask a new question with all the information you have linking to this one.  If it's just to add an image to expand the question, then I think that's OK.

Answer (score 5):

Great answer by @Knightshound although I would probably add that if you want to do this manually using the `Split Features` tool then make sure you enable the **snapping** options, set a tolerance and **snap it to vertex**.

Alternatively, you could select your desired line and use the `Explode lines` tool which will split your line at **each** vertex (you can't specify the vertices). Save this as a temporary layer, delete the line in your original layer and copy/paste the split lines from the result back to your original layer.

(*I would opt for @Knightshound's method*).